# Ordering of Tensor indices: a specific example

Tags: tensor-calculus, conventions

As an example of construcing tensors out of the product of other tensors I found the following example.

$$T_{i}{}^j{}_{kl}=A_i{}^jB_{kl}+C_m{}^{mj}D_{ikl}$$

But I am a bit confused about the specific ordering of the indices. Of course in general the order is important (in case of non symmetrical Tensors). While I agree that the first term $A_i{}^jB_{kl}$ gives an ordering as proposed looking at the second term $C_m{}^{mj}D_{ikl}$ I would suggest something like $T_{ikl}{}^j$.

So in general how does one determine a correct and consistent ordering of the indices?

Answer (score 2):

The order of indices is indeed important, but we can define tensors with inverted indices if we wish: for instance, the tensor $A_{ij}$ is in general different from $A_{ji}$, but if you are given $A_{ij}$ you can define $B_{ij} = A_{ji}$.

This is somewhat like defining the transpose of a matrix: it is a different matrix, but still a valid one.

So, the equation you have written is valid, since there is no requirement that the indices on the left-hand side should be exactly in the same order as the ones on the right-hand side.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So in the case of general outer product of tensors every permutation of indices is a valid notation as long as one respects the number of upper and lower components? Or am I wrong?

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, that's right. In fact, often it is useful to "symmetrize" or "antisymmetrize" two or more indices, for example, the electromagnetic field strength tensor $F_{\mu \nu}$ is defined as $\partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu$. In this case, we are antisymmetrizing: considering all the possible permutations of the indices, and putting a minus sign in front of the odd permutations.